# Installing tensorflow on ubuntu with GPU support

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, machine-learning, ubuntu-18.04

Okay so. I have big problem and I wasn't able to solve it for days. I've searched like every thread on this and still can't do it.

Firstly. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with python 3.6 and Nvidia Gforce 920M graphic card. I have Cuda 9.0 (also tried with 9.1 and 9.2).

I was trying to install tensorflow-gpu but every time I import it I get same error.

`2018-12-09 01:43:41.324778: F tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:37] The TensorFlow library was compiled to use AVX instructions, but these aren't available on your machine.
Aborted (core dumped)`

I also tried with Anaconda and still no luck.

Can you guys help me somehow? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so. Switching to python 2.7 and installing tensorflow-gpu fix this problem. I still have no idea why but this is a workaround for this problem. If you guys have any idea how to fix it for Python 3.6 post it but untill then just use Python 2.7.

Happy coding!